# Should I avoid creating new instances of WebDriver all the time? C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

At present, every time I want to do a new action in WebDriver I *think* I am creating  a new WebDriver instance:

```
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("locator")).Click();
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("locator")).Click();
```

Then my code for Instance:

```
public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }
```

Can I, or rather *should* I change this to not creating instances like this all the time? I'm not sure if this is a bad thing to do, but it seems a bit odd.

Thanks,

sad muso

Comment: Why do you think you are creating new instances? the code you posted accesses the same static instance, which is a bad practice if you want to run your UT's in parallel, but it is definitely not creating new instances

Comment: Ah okay cool, it's obviously a case that I don't understand it then. I will also need to look into changing it so that it can be run in parallel later down the line. Thank you